# The meaning of this symbol $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, definition

Does this symbol $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ means that if $f$ in $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ then it is continuous on $[0,1]$ and its first derivative $f'$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$?

I have the function $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ as an example that troubles my mind.

Any explanation will be helpful!

Comment: You are right $f(x) =x^{\frac{1}{3}} \notin C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $f$ is differentiable in $[0,1]$ and its derivative is continuous. Note that this automatically implies that $f$ itself is continuous, so you don't have to mention that in the definition of $C^1$.

In general, $C^k([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the space of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that are differentiable $k$ times and their $k$th derivative is continuous.

Comment: what about my example?

Comment: $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is not differentiable at $0$, as we have $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{h^{\frac{1}{3}}}{h}=\infty$. Hence it is not in $C^1$.

Comment: Is the derivative should be continuous on $[0,1]$ also? or on the open interval only?

Comment: No, it has to be continuous on the closed interval.